# Simple javascript for wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am busy with a wordpress site. I am using a plugin  called wp-imageflow2, it uses the discription of the image when its upload to make a link, from what I gathered it looks for http to make a link. I need the images to link to a mailto tag.

So far I have a link to a html page in the description of the imageflow. Within the html page I have the code below. It works fine except it uses the html link in the address bar. How would I first create a new tab, open the email address in the email client and with a delay close the new tab. That should leave you on your original page. Is this possible ?

```
<script>
 function myFunc(){
 location.href="mailto:name@name.co.za";
 window.open('newwindow', config='height=50, width=50')
 window.setTimeout("window.close()", 1000);

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunc();">
</body>
```

Comment: "You do not have my permission to open my e-mail client. Stop trying to write code that does so." ~ Everyone on the internet.

Comment: can't you just patch the plugin to accept mailto adresses insted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wp-imageflow2.php row 227

```
if (($link == 'true') && (substr($attachment->post_content,0,7) == 'http://')) $linkurl = $attachment->post_content;
```

just add a few more lines here:

```
else if (($link == 'true') && (substr($attachment->post_content,0,8) == 'https://')) $linkurl = $attachment->post_content;
else if (($link == 'true') && (substr($attachment->post_content,0,7) == 'mailto:')) $linkurl = $attachment->post_content;
else if (($link == 'true') && (substr($attachment->post_content,0,6) == 'ftp://')) $linkurl = $attachment->post_content;
```

Comment: Hi Puggan,

Thanks for your reply. In theory that's exactly what I want to do. That doesnt seem to work though, it doesn't seem to find the mailto: link, just ignores it and brings up the lightbox overlay. Any ideas ?

Kind Regards,
Charl.

Comment: oh, sorry, the mailto shouldn't have the extra //, updating my answers by replacing "mailto://" with "mailto:", and lowering the length from 9 to 7

Comment: there is no extra //. what do you mean ?